# How can I set WebHostUrl in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack 4.0.17 and the `Host.Instance.Config.WebHostUrl` is always null.

I'm using ServiceStack as a standalone web application - no MVC or ASP.NET - that is being served by IIS Express (VS2013) in integrated mode.

Is there any required configuration to run ServiceStack as a standalone web application that I may be missing?

If someone is having the same issue I created a **temporary** workaround that can be used in the Application_BeginRequest:

```
 private void SetApplicationUrl()
        {
            if (_applicationUrl == null)
            {
                lock (_applicationUrlLock)
                {
                    if (ServiceStackHost.Instance.Config.WebHostUrl != null) return;

                    // Remove the page path information.
                    Regex regex = new Regex("(" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath + ")$");

                    _applicationUrl = regex.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, string.Empty);

                    ServiceStackHost.Instance.Config.WebHostUrl = _applicationUrl;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All ServiceStack configuration should be set in the `AppHost.Configure()` with the **SetConfig** method, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    WebHostUrl = myBaseUrl
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I get my myBaseUrl inside the AppHost.Configure? There's no Request available inside .NET's [Application Start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518057/request-is-not-available-in-this-context)

Comment: It's set once at Application startup, not at runtime.

Comment: Got it. I thought it could be set at runtime.

Comment: @CarlosMendes Nope but depending what you want to do, you way want to override `ServiceStackHost.ResolveAbsoluteUrl()` in your AppHost class, which gets called whenever ServiceStack want's to resolve a Url.